# ArcPy - What's the syntax for comparing a variable against two values for Boolean?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, raster

I'm a student trying to get a Boolean `True`/`False` value based on if a raster cell value falls within a given range, and I want to clean it up so that I can process each separate range as only one new raster. Basically, I just want to get values that are, say, between 5 and 20 for one raster, the values that are between 150 and 270 for another raster, and between 41 and 43 for a third raster, and then get the composite of those three.

The way I've got it written is fine, but I want to clean it up a little bit. However, I have two Boolean operators for each individual range, and every time I try to combine the operators into one per raster, ArcGIS tells me that it cannot determine the Boolean value, and that my statement is ambiguous.

Why does this happen? Here's what I have:

```
from arcpy.sa import *

outraster1 = arcpy.sa.Slope("Elevation")
outraster1.save("slope")
slope = arcpy.Raster("slope")

outraster2 = arcpy.sa.Aspect("Elevation")
outraster2.save("aspect")
aspect = arcpy.Raster("aspect")

landuse = arcpy.Raster("landcover.tif")

goodslope = 5 < slope
goodslope2 = slope < 20
bestslope = goodslope & goodslope2

goodaspect = 150 < aspect
goodaspect2 = aspect < 270
bestaspect = goodaspect & goodaspect2

goodforest = 41 <= landuse
goodforest2 = landuse <= 43
bestforest = goodforest & goodforest2

bestfinal = bestslope & bestaspect & bestforest
bestfinal.save("challenge9_1")
```

The above gives me what I want, but I'm not sure why I can't just use this:

```
goodslope = ((slope>5) and (slope<20))
goodaspect = ((aspect>150) and (aspect<270))
goodforest = ((41 <= landuse) and (landuse <= 43))
goodfinal = goodslope and goodaspect and goodforest
goodfinal.save("challenge9_1")
```

Is there a reason why the syntax above keeps giving me an ambiguous error?

Comment: - can you add the error?

Comment: Try replacing and by * , it's the same thing

Comment: Last line should be Con(a* b* c,1), also and in raster calculator is &